# Pywintypes Error with Pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am trying to use Pyinstaller to turn a short script into an EXE. I am running windows 10 and using 32 bit python.

I am getting this error:

```
pywintypes.error: (2, 'LoadLibraryEx', 'The system cannot find the file     specified.')
```

The script is:

```
#text->PNG->STL
from pylab import imread
from scipy.ndimage import gaussian_filter
from stl_tools import numpy2stl, text2png

print "enter name"
patientName = raw_input()

text = (patientName)
# save png
text2png(text, 'Tempfile', fontsize=90)
# read from rendered png
A = 256 * imread("Tempfile.png")
A = A.mean(axis=2)  # grayscale projection
A = gaussian_filter(A.max() - A, 1.0)
#changed scale from .15
numpy2stl(A, "DAVE111.stl", scale=0.85, mask_val=5, max_width=14)
print "done"
```

The error I receive when using Pyinstaller (I've also tried cx_freeze and py2exe ) is quite long, but ends with:

```
 File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\winresource.py", line 168, in GetResources
    hsrc = win32api.LoadLibraryEx(filename, 0, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE)
pywintypes.error: (2, 'LoadLibraryEx', 'The system cannot find the file specified.')
```

I have been tinkering with Spec files and trying everything, and just can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be appreciated! I've also tried re-downloading win32api with no luck.

Thanks,

Dave